# Remove downloaded URLs from a text file

Tags: bash, 18.04, wget

I have a text file containing a bunch of URLs (more like 500 or more), now I used wget to download few files and I want to remove URL of the files downloaded from the text file.

Comment: What does a URL look like in the file?

Comment: Like a normal url `http://something.deb` and one line per url

Comment: Is the URL a whole line.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the text including these URLs!

Comment: Here is the link to [sample] (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tXSGK6yqY4/)

Comment: From the looks of your sample, this looks like a file that you shouldn't be editing. Where is this file located? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I created it using `apt-get --print-uris`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a bunch of deb files. And in the same directory you have a text file named `file_list` where each line is a download link for all of those deb files. We can get the names of all of deb files using glob pattern (*deb) and using for loop we use sed to remove matched line in-place of the `file_list`:

```
for i in *deb;
do
    sed -i "/"$i"/d" file_list
done
```

Just to be safe, copy  the `file_list` first before you run the command.